# compliant formatted email

Tags: php, email, formatting, specifications

i've been using php's pear Mail & Mail_Mime libraries to send well formatted html emails with/without attachments.  some hosting companies don't have these libraries installed, and are reluctant to do so.

so, i'm looking for a good technical source, tutorial, readable spec so i can write my own class using php's mail function... do you know of a good one?

thanks,

rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [instructions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php) in the PEAR manual for installing using ftp. I have successfully used this to install PEAR on a web host that didn't provide it. You could give that a go before looking for alternatives.

Comment: thanks... i should really do this instead of writing my own.  makes more sense!

Answer (score 0):

The hosting company doesn't need to install PEAR libraries on the server for you to use them. You can include them with your code.

If you're looking to move away from PEAR, I'd suggest trying [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html) on for size.

Comment: i'll have a look at zend... its pretty big though.  i've used the pdf classes, which are good.

Answer (score 0):

The [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) class may be exactly what you are after, or might be close enough that you can extend it to suit your needs.